# Root delay and Root dispersion values in NTP protocol?

Tags: ntp

I'm implementing NTP Server and client (for the first time). I've few questions for which I couldn't found detailed explanation. Please help me with the below topics.
1. What is root dispersion ,precision and poll fields in the NTP packet format
2. Can i assign any values to them or shall i need to calculate?

```
   Please suggest me....
```

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful response from one of the NTP mailing lists. (I assume you are already reading http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt)

Answer (score 0):

So a good place to start would be the [Official NTP Docs](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/index.html)

```
rootdisp - total dispersion to the primary reference clock
precision - precision (log2 s)
poll - poll messages sent (every n sec)
```

You don't directly assign any of those values - you need to read up about the `ntp.conf` file and which directives you should use there for your specific environment.

You may also want to look at an answer I gave on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/843580/ntpd-not-updating-time-date-on-centos/845013#845013)

You didn't say which OS you are using, or which ntp client so this is all generic stuff based on linux. If you would like specific help then please expand your question with some examples and some of the reference material you have already looked at else it will be very hard to help.